# Store passwords local with plain text access on WinPE

Tags: encryption, passwords, hash, password-management, .net

I have an application that needs to store Network Credentials for a Network Drive/Share on the disk. The user shouldn't need to enter the password every time.
The OS is **WinPE**, so he cannot map the drive once and it will stay there.

Limitation:

- I need the password in plain text, to map the drive.
- The program should work without an additional password that the user has to enter.

Thoughts:

- **Hash + Salt** is not reversible, so I cannot get the password in plain text.
- An **encrypted password** is not safe, because the program has to store the key. If someone looks inside the code he will get the key and decrypt the password.
- I cannot use the "Protect Data" interface of windows, because I use WinPE. [Protect Data Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata?view=netframework-4.8)

The program is written in C#.
Maybe someone has a good idea about my problem. Thanks!